# Does ContentResolver notifyChange method notifies also detail Uri's?

Tags: android, uri, datacontract, android-contentresolver

During applying data I use `notifyChange` with an `Uri`.

Let's say I notify `content://com.package.my/items`.

I have also detail `Activity` that displays data from `content://com.package.my/items/1`.

Does notifying 'general' `Uri` results also in 'detail' `Uri` being notified?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method `notifyChange` sends a notification for the detailed URI. 
But if you register a `ContentObserver` at `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri uri, boolean notifyForDescendents, ContentObserver observer)` you can register a base `Uri` to be notified if any descendant `Uri` has been changed (is used to send change notification).

I assume you have a `ContentProvider` and that you query a `Cursor` from that `ContentProvider` through a `ContentResolver`. If you set the notification URI on the `Cursor` that you return in the `ContentProvider.query()` method, your `CursorAdapter` will automatically update the view if the notification URI or any of its descendants change (see source of [Cursor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/database/Cursor.java#Cursor.setNotificationUri%28android.content.ContentResolver,android.net.Uri%29)). If you change the data with you `ContentProvider` be sure to send a notification in `update,insert,delete` of your `ContentProvider`.

---